# Como ler várias listas dentro do Pandas Dataframe Python

Tags: python, lista, pandas

Estou tentando colocar varias listas dentro do PandasDataFrame, mas ele está lendo somento a última lista

Como ler todas listas abaixo e colocar no  Data Frame do Pandas?

Código Scrapy:

```python
import requests
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://statusinvest.com.br/'
response = requests.get(url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')

# coletando todos os ativos com um laço for
lista_ativos = []

for ativos in soup.find_all(class_="info w-100"):
  
    # Obtain the text from the received
    # tags
    lista_ativos=ativos.get_text()
    lista_ativos = lista_ativos.split()
    print(lista_ativos)
```

Saída:

```
['SUZB3', 'SUZANO', 'S.A.', 'arrow_upward', '6,70%', 'R$', '57,33']

['BRAP4', 'BRADESPAR', 'arrow_upward', '4,97%', 'R$', '34,43']

['KLBN11', 'KLABIN', 'arrow_upward', '4,83%', 'R$', '24,32']

['COTY34', 'COTY.', 'INC.', 'arrow_downward', '-9,38%', 'R$', '20,57']
```

Saída:

```python
## PANDAS #########################
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(lista_ativos)

print(df)
```

Saída:

```
                0

0          TPRY34

1        TAPESTRY

2             INC

3  arrow_downward

4          -9,40%

5              R$

6          167,30
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes da solução, repare que **todas** as listas têm que possuir o mesmo número de elementos. Mesmo que o elemento seja `None` ou string vazio `''`. Alguns dos exemplos que vc passou, possuem `S.A.` ou `INC.`

Solução: Use `pd.DataFrame.from_records()`

Veja exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

lista = [
    ['SUZB3', 'SUZANO', 'arrow_upward', '6,70%', 'R$', '57,33'],
    ['BRAP4', 'BRADESPAR', 'arrow_upward', '4,97%', 'R$', '34,43']
    ['KLBN11', 'KLABIN', 'arrow_upward', '4,83%', 'R$', '24,32'],
    ['COTY34', 'COTY.', 'arrow_downward', '-9,38%', 'R$', '20,57']
]


df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lista, columns=["id", "empresa", "arrow", "val1", "moeda", "val2"])

df
       id    empresa           arrow    val1 moeda   val2
0   SUZB3     SUZANO    arrow_upward   6,70%    R$  57,33
1   BRAP4  BRADESPAR    arrow_upward   4,97%    R$  34,43
2  KLBN11     KLABIN    arrow_upward   4,83%    R$  24,32
3  COTY34      COTY.  arrow_downward  -9,38%    R$  20,57
```

Em tempo: As colunas `val1` e `val2` são do tipo `object`. Para este caso, todos os valores são do tipo `str`.

Answer (score -1):

## coletando todos os ativos com um laço for

lista_ativos = []

for ativos in soup.find_all(class_="info w-100"):

```
# Obtain the text from the received
# tags
lista=ativos.get_text().split()
for i in lista:
  lista_ativos.append(i) 
 
print(lista_ativos)
```